# PHP SQLite PRAGMA journal_mode = wal and readonly users

Tags: php, sqlite, readonly, pragma, sqlite-journal-mode

I read that WAL mode allows a user users to read while during a write session.
Therefore I should be able to have 3 sessions reading data and one writing data at the same time, This sounds like a good thing for my use, so I figured I should define the session type so the system knows if this session is a reader or a writer using the connection flag.
http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php#refsect1-sqlite3.open-parameters
It states here that if the session is not closed cleanly that the `-shm` and `-wal` files are not removed
https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#write_ahead_log_wal_files
After a read session the temporary files are not removed, thus meaning the session was not cleanly closed despite calling the close function and it returning `true`, so why are the files not being deleted when using the `SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY` flag? Should I even use a flag at all?

Comment: Please read the [actual documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#readonly).

Comment: I have read that before, it is not on readonly media

Comment: The media itself does not matter, "write access is required".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've conflated SQLite's concept of 'readers' and 'writers' with the ability of the PHP SQLite3 driver to open a file as read-only.

Using the `SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY` flag will cause PHP to block all write operations with a warning:

> Warning: SQLite3::exec(): attempt to write a readonly database in ...

This can be useful if you want to ensure no writes can happen from your application (perhaps as a security measure). But it's not related to SQLite's readers and writers.

As [pointed out by CL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44331249/php-sqlite-pragma-journal-mode-wal-and-readonly-users#comment75676188_44331249) all processes accessing the WAL mode database need write access. This is explicitly [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#readonly):

> Also, if multiple processes are to access a WAL mode database, then all processes should run under user or group IDs that give them write access to the database files, the WAL file, the shared memory -shm file, and the containing directory.

And mentioned as a disadvantage at the top of that page:

> It is not possible to open read-only WAL databases. The opening process must have write privileges for "-shm" wal-index shared memory file associated with the database, if that file exists, or else write access on the directory containing the database file if the "-shm" file does not exist.

SQLite itself decides if a process is a reader or writer when it receives a command to execute. For example, if a single process executes a `SELECT`, then a `INSERT`, then a `SELECT` again it changes from reader to writer to reader. SQLite will handle locking (potentially blocking other processes) automatically. (Note that this is a simplified explanation that can be quite different with different modes of database operation.)

For your purposes you shouldn't use the `SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY` flag.